# How do you structure a ManyToMany relationship with itself?

Tags: ruby, many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many

I'm trying to model a database for my website and I'm trying to conceptualize how one would go about structuring a table that has a ManyToMany relationship with itself. I'm very new to programming and web development so explaining it in in laymen terms as best as possible is preferred. No need for specific code, just theory behind how one would structure such a database. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do and the best way I can explain it... using cats!

Let's say I have a table that lists cats and the relationship between itself is a representation of their mating pattern. Cats will mate with many other cats so each cat is a OneToMany relationship with a bunch of other cats. The initial thought would be to separate the cats into two tables of Male and Female and solve this issue classically with an intermediate table holding keys, however, this doesn't allow data for homosexual cats or bisexual cats. So how does one represent the mating details of these cats structurally in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Make another table called mating with two foreign key columns refering to your cat table.